# Using PIE CSS in WordPress. "localizing" styles

Tags: theme-development, css

I read before I can use wp_localize_script to replace a string in a file (adding path to admin-ajax). what if I want to do something similar, but to the template directory for CSS?

PIE will get the URL relative to the document not CSS

Comment: Not sure if I understand your question correctly, but why would you want to localize your css files?

Answer (score 1):

I assume you're trying to integrate CSS3PIE (PIE.htc) into your theme. Here's one solution:

http://css3pie.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=4&t=8